# How do you blit/draw a sprite in Pygame with lower opacity?

Tags: python, pygame, opacity

I'm trying to blit some fog into a game, but I've run into a problem where I've realized that the fog is too thick/opacity to high. I want to blit it with an even lower opacity, but I'm not too sure how and the tutorials I've found online don't work/already expect you to know how to.

Just in case you're wondering how the code is written:

```py
screen.blit(fog, (0, 0))
```

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.8, just in case that matters

EDIT EDIT: I'm using Pygame 2.0.0, just in case that also matters

Answer (score 1):

You don't blit at lower opacity, you blit a surface that has a lower opacity.

Use `surface.set_alpha()` to change the opacity of the fog before you blit it.

Docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha

Also, if you're loading in your fog from an image, be sure to use `surface.convert_alpha()` on it, or else it will not register the transparency in the image format.

Answer (score 0):

[`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) actually blends a *Surface* onto the target *Surface*, dependent on the alpha channel of the *Surface*. All you have to do is change the alpha channel of the `fog`. Use [`set_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha) to set the alpha value for the full Surface image:

> Set the current alpha value for the Surface. When blitting this Surface onto a destination, the pixels will be drawn slightly transparent. The alpha value is an integer from 0 to 255, 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.

If you want to apply a 50% transparent fog:

```py
fog.set_alpha(127)
screen.blit(fog, (0, 0))
```